# Parallel creation of a match-table

Tags: java, parallel-processing, guava, java-8

I have two sets of Objects (X,Y) and I want to compare all of the elements in X with all of the elements in Y and write the resulting values into a match-table.

My first approach was to have to have two for loops, which iterate over the sets and write the result to a table.

```
Table<Object, Object, Double>matchTable = TreeBasedTable.create(new ObjectComparator(), new ObjectComparator());

for (Object x : X) {
    for (Object y : Y) {
        double diff = comparator.diff(x, y);
        matchTable.put(x, y, diff);
    }
}
```

Since with Java 8 there are more possibilities for parallel processing I wanted to do the same thing but in parallel. My first attempt looks like this, but I think this is not the way it should be, I think it would be better to use some `Collector` to create the table and write to it.

```
Function<Pair<Object>, Boolean> colF = pair -> {
    double diff = comparator.diff(pair.x, pair.y);
    matchTable.put(pair.x, pair.y, diff);
    return true;
};
Function<Object, Long> rowF = x -> {
    return Y.parallelStream().map(y -> {
        return colF.apply(new Pair<Object>(x, y));
    }).count();
};
long count = X.parallelStream().map(rowF).count();
```

(I just call the `count()` because else it would be lazy execution. `Pair` is just a class which holds two objects.)

Comment: `TreeBasedTable` is not synchronized, you cannot do concurrent writes. Doing so as a side-effect of the mapping is also a bad idéal, IMHO.

Comment: "Idea", not "idéal"...

Comment: Yes, I know that this is a bad idea and this is why I ask this question. I've just added this example to make clear, what I want in the end. But thanks for making this explicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things going on here. The first is how to linearize a two-dimensional iteration into a stream, and the second is how to store the results into some data structure.

A useful idiom to linearize a 2D iteration into a stream is to drive the outer stream with the row values, and call `flatMap` to return a stream of all column values for that row. This often requires some kind of pair structure, but you've bought into that already. The code would look something like this:

```
X.stream()
 .flatMap(x -> Y.stream().map(y -> new Pair(x, y)))
 .forEach(System.out::println);
```

This generates all the pairs into a linear stream and prints them out.

I don't know how Guava's `TreeBasedTable` works. It appears not to be thread-safe, but that's OK, since the stream collector can deal with non-thread-safe. However, collectors require intermediate results to be merged, but I don't know how to do that with Guava `Table` objects. Somebody else will have to provide that information.

If you want to collect the values into a map keyed by pairs (instead of a table), you could do something like this:

```
X.stream()
 .flatMap(x -> Y.stream().map(y -> new Pair(x, y)))
 .collect(toMap(pair -> pair, pair -> pair.a + pair.b));
```

If you were to run the stream in parallel, you should use `toConcurrentMap` instead of `toMap`.